# python magic square finder for arbitrary numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, combinatorics

I wrote this code to get all possible magic squares that can be made with a list you put in. The only contraints are that the count of numbers is a square and that each number is unique. It even works for complex numbers.

I dont know how good the performance is, it needs about 1.5 to 2hours to find all 7040 4*4 magic squares with numbers from 1 to 16.

The finding strategy is to get all possible permutations of all subsets of the number set that sum to the magic number and then put these as a whole row into the matrix, recursively.

All feedback is welcome :)

```
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import combinations, permutations
from math import sqrt


def main(numbers):
    '''Finds all magic squares that can be made with
    the given set of numbers.'''
    global dim, magicnumber, emptyrow
    dim = int(sqrt(len(numbers)))
    magicnumber = sum(numbers) / dim
    emptyrow = ["" for _ in range(dim)]
    current = [emptyrow for _ in range(dim)]
    groups = possibilities(numbers, dim, magicnumber)
    placeRow(current, groups, row=0)
    report(solutions)


def possibilities(numbers, dim, magicnumber):
    '''Returns a list of all the ways to reach
    the magic number with the given list of numbers.'''
    combos = [
        list(x) for x in list(
            combinations(
                numbers,
                dim)) if sum(x) == magicnumber]
    possibilities = [list(permutations(x)) for x in combos]
    possibilities = [[list(y) for y in x] for x in possibilities]
    possibilities = [item for sublist in possibilities for item in sublist]
    return possibilities


def remainding_possibilities(matrix, possibilities):
    '''Returns the remainding possibilities once the matrix has entries.'''
    entries = {item for sublist in matrix for item in sublist}
    remainders = [x for x in possibilities if entries.isdisjoint(x)]
    return remainders


def placeRow(matrix, groups, row=0):
    '''Recursive function that fills the matrix row wise
    and puts magic squares into "solutions" list.'''
    godeeper = False
    current = matrix
    for group in groups:
        current[row] = group  # put the whole group into the row
        if emptyrow in current:
            remainders = remainding_possibilities(current, groups)
            godeeper = placeRow(current, remainders, row=row + 1)
        else:
            if check(current):
                solutions.append(deepcopy(current))
                current[row] = emptyrow
                return False
            else:
                current[row] = emptyrow
        if godeeper is False:
            current[row] = emptyrow
    return False


def check(matrix):
    '''Returns false if current matrix is not or cant be made
    into a magic square.'''
    # rows
    # not needed because we fill row wise
    # for x in range(dim):
    #     if "" not in matrix[x]:
    #         if sum(matrix[x]) != magicnumber:
    #             return False
    # only if we have positive numbers only
    #         else:
    #             if sum(transposed[x]) > magicnumber:
    #                 return False

    # diagonals
    diag1 = [matrix[x][x] for x in range(dim)]
    if "" not in diag1:
        if sum(diag1) != magicnumber:
            return False
    # only if we have positive numbers only
    else:
        if sum(diag1) > magicnumber:
            return False

    diag2 = [matrix[x][dim - 1 - x] for x in range(dim)]
    if "" not in diag2:
        if sum(diag2) != magicnumber:
            return False
    # only if we have positive numbers only
    else:
        if sum(diag2) > magicnumber:
            return False

    # columns
    transposed = transpose(matrix)
    for x in range(dim):
        if "" not in transposed[x]:
            if sum(transposed[x]) != magicnumber:
                return False
        # only if we have positive numbers only
        else:
            if sum(transposed[x]) > magicnumber:
                return False

    return True


def transpose(matrix):
    '''Transpose a matrix.'''
    return list(map(list, zip(*matrix)))


def report(solutions):
    ''' Writes solutions to text file.'''
    with open(f"solutions.txt", 'w') as txtfile:
        txtfile.write(
            f"Found {len(solutions)} magic squares:\n\n")
        for solution in solutions:
            for line in solution:
                for entry in line:
                    txtfile.write(f"{entry}" + " ")
                txtfile.write("\n")
            txtfile.write("\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Some inputs for main().
    complex3 = [(complex(x, y))
                for x in range(1, 4)
                for y in range(1, 4)]
    complex4 = [(complex(x, y))
                for x in range(1, 5)
                for y in range(1, 5)]
    complex5 = [(complex(x, y))
                for x in range(1, 6)
                for y in range(1, 6)]
    test3 = [x for x in range(1, 10)]
    test4 = [x for x in range(1, 17)]
    test5 = [x for x in range(1, 26)]
    solutions = []

    main(complex3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just reviewing the function `possibilities`.

This function is doing a lot of unnecessary extra work and I think it would be worth your while trying to understand why you made it so complicated.

The first steps are: (i) find all combinations of `dim` elements of `numbers`; (ii) convert the combinations to a list; (iii) filter for combinations that add up to the magic number; (iv) convert each combination to a list.

```
combos = [
    list(x) for x in list(
        combinations(
            numbers,
            dim)) if sum(x) == magicnumber]
```

What is the purpose of steps (ii) and (iv)? If you omit these steps then this line simplifies to:

```
combos = [x for x in combinations(numbers, dim) if sum(x) == magicnumber]
```

and this works just as well as the original.

The next steps are: (v) find the permutations of each combination; (vi) turn each group of permutations into a list; (vii) turn each permutation into a list; (viii) flatten the list of lists of permutations into a single list.

```
possibilities = [list(permutations(x)) for x in combos]
possibilities = [[list(y) for y in x] for x in possibilities]
possibilities = [item for sublist in possibilities for item in sublist]
```

But again, steps (vi) and (vii) are unnecessary, and steps (v) and (viii) can be combined into one, leaving you with:

```
possibilities = [p for x in combos for p in permutations(x)]
```

and the definition of `combos` can be inlined here, getting:

```
return [p for c in combinations(numbers, dim)
        if sum(c) == magicnumber
        for p in permutations(c)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code just "grew" that way and then I couldnt refactor it to a shorter version like you did. Would you be so kind to also look at `remainding_possibilities`, because most of the run time comes from that function.

Comment: When code "just grows" that means that you don't fully understand how it works and you've lost control of it. The way to regain understanding is to work through the steps in detail on a small example, so that you can see how each step transforms the data structures.

Comment: I dont think we are talking about the same thing. What I meant was as I was writing it, I changed it many times until it worked and then I couldnt go back or rephrase it because I am not good enough to say it in another way. That is exactly why I post here.